# Octave return sorted array of string with values altered

Tags: octave

I'm trying to ordering by name a list of files, but when I used sort Octave function the returned array has values altered, see code bellow:

```
files = dir('*.ASC');
newFiles;

for i = 1:length(files(:,1))
    newFiles = [newFiles; files(i, 1).name];
endfor;
```

newFiles =

```
ALA0.ASC
ALA15.ASC
ALA150.ASC
ALA30.ASC
ALA45.ASC
ALA60.ASC
ALA90.ASC
```

sort(newFiles)

```
ans =

ALA0...A
ALA10.ACC
ALA10.ASC
ALA30.ASC
ALA45.ASC
ALA650ASC
ALA95ASSSC
```

How can I get my column vector sorted with the originals values? or if is there other way to sorted the filenames gotten from dir function?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a cell:

```
files = dir('*.*');
newFiles={};

for i = 1:length(files(:,1))
    newFiles(i)=files(i, 1).name;
endfor;
```

For what I see dir already produces a sorted list

```
octave:30> newFiles
newFiles =
{
  [1,1] = ALA01.asc
  [1,2] = ALA20.asc
  [1,3] = ALA33.asc
  [1,4] = ALA41.asc
}

octave:31> sort(newFiles)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = ALA01.asc
  [1,2] = ALA20.asc
  [1,3] = ALA33.asc
  [1,4] = ALA41.asc
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work all values in the sorted newFiles are ALA0.ASC

Comment: It works for me on Octave 5.2. How have you defined newFiles at the beginning ? Please note the  `{}`

Comment: See here the results: https://pastebin.com/xPurwKnG. Also I'm using Octave 5.2.0

Comment: the issue is that you are looking for a unique sort, and your new files are eventually already included.

Comment: I though the same, but I tested outside of my work directory: https://pastebin.com/Ye0VYvjG, I also have tried with empty cell newFiles = {}; https://pastebin.com/5saCViiM

Comment: it seems to work if you are only adding new files, or I do not understand your expectation ?

Comment: No, it isn't work, see the pastebin test. I spect read a list of files from a directory and ordered by names.

Comment: So you are starting from an empty list ? Why are you fiilling `newFiles` with values before adding the dir resutls ?

Comment: Question 1: Yes. Question 2: I only tested your proposed  solution.

Comment: see solution with empty starting list

Comment: I tested, I shared a link in one of the comment above https://pastebin.com/5saCViiM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215120/discussion-between-matzeri-and-omixam).